# CA ERwin Data Modeler Community edition written on PDF from Erwin

Tags: pdf, erwin

I tried to create a PDF from a model in ERwin Data Modeler r9. I managed to create the PDF. However "CA ERwin Data Modeler Community edition" is written on several places in the PDF. This looks bad and makes it impossible to read the entire model. How can I remove this text?

FYI: I have bought the license.

If you need further clarification don't hesitate to ask. Thank you!

Comment: i have used crystal reoprt to create PDF. Did you tried that??

Answer (score 0):

Once you have registered the license, the watermark should disappear. If it doesn't, I'd call CA support